# Multiple questions on equation 1.6 after deriving Planck's law on page 5 (Schwartz QFT)

Tags: quantum-field-theory, energy, statistical-mechanics, temperature, integration

After deriving Planck's law for the expectation energy of a single mode, Schwartz takes the limit $L \rightarrow \infty$ and turns the sums into integrals. The average total energy of the blackbody becomes

$$\int^ \omega d^3\vec{n}\dfrac{\hbar\omega}{e^{\hbar\omega_n\beta}-1} = \int_{-1}^{1} d\cos\theta \int_{0}^{2\pi}d\phi \int_{0}^{\omega}d|\vec{n}|\dfrac{|\vec{n}|^2\hbar\omega}{e^{\hbar\omega_n\beta}-1} \\= 4\pi\hbar\dfrac{L^3}{8\pi^3}\int_{0}^{\omega} d\omega' \dfrac{\omega'^3}{e^{\hbar\omega_n'\beta}-1}.\tag{1.6}$$

My questions are

1. How does the first integral turn into integrals of $d\cos\theta$ and $d\phi$? Is it because we take into consideration the black body is a sphere? Please correct me on this I thought it was supposed to be a box with $L^3 = V$.
2. The last integral is what bothers me the most, maybe I skipped my calc class but how does the differential $d|\vec{n}|$ and $|\vec{n}|$ in the integrand simply changes to $d\omega'$ and $\omega'$. What does it physically mean to do this to the integral in this case?

EDIT:
The integral $\int_{-1}^{1} d\cos\theta$ bothers me too since it's an even integral shouldn't the whole thing go to zero? EDIT: the question in the edit is answered

Comment: $\int_{-1}^1 d\cos\theta= \cos\theta\Bigl\vert_{-1}^1=2$.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero the result would be $\cos(1) - \cos(-1) = 0.54\cdots - 0.54\cdots = 0$?

Comment: the variabale is "cos theta" not "theta"

Comment: @Wihtedeka oh that makes sense thanks

Comment: Right.  I wrote it in a confusing way.  You can also write as $\int_0^{\pi} \sin\theta d\theta$ where it’s probably clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last line has an $\omega$ inside the integral without any $\prime$ or $n$ label. This should be $\omega^\prime$. Your first line has two instances of $\omega$ inside the integral without any $\prime$ or $n$ label. These should be $\omega_n$.

Once these corrections are made, you need only recognize that Schwartz is using a substitution based on the dispersion relation (1.3). That is, he sets
\begin{equation}
|\vec{n}| = \frac{L}{2\pi} \omega_n
\end{equation}
and then renames $\omega_n$ to $\omega^\prime$ since it's a dummy variable.

Comment: Thanks I understand now!